# Лицензированный шрифт на сайт

Tags: лицензирование, вёрстка, css, шрифты

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как быть с лицензированными шрифтами.

Хочется прикрутить [шрифт](http://store1.adobe.com/cfusion/store/html/index.cfm?store=OLS-US&event=displayFont&code=BIRQ10005000) на сайт. Несложно видеть ценник в 30$ и "многа букав" о лицензии в которых тяжело разобраться. Посему вопросы.

1. Можно ли как-то обойти лицензию? Перерисовать шрифт самому?
2. Если купить его за эти 30$, то можно ли выкладывать в сеть материалы с использованием этого шрифта (например текст картинкой)?
3. Если купить за все те же 30$, можно ли использовать font-face? Ведь по сути это означает открытый доступ к файлам шрифта.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Если вы будете подключать шрифт через **@font-face**, то он будет лежать на сервере вашего сайта, и его будет легко украсть (*о чём вы и писали*). Лучше, если ваш лицензионный шрифт будет реализован при помощи **JavaScript** или же с помощью **картинок**.

А ещё лучше найти более-менее похожий, но **бесплатный** шрифт.

Comment: Насчет найти более-менее похожий - согласен. Простой и очевидный вариант. С картинками то же все ясно. JS-решение подразумевает использование шрифта, но в защищенном виде, или то же подмена буковок?

Comment: JavaScript использует возможности браузера для отрисовки этих букв.

Comment: А почему человека, купившего шрифт, должна заботить сложность кражи? Украл -- выпил -- в тюрьму, но это уже заботы правоохранительных органов. Тот, кто держит шрифт на сайте, законов не нарушает, если в лицензии явно не указано обратное. Он ведь не для скачивания его выложил